# Does before_save stops a paperclip upload on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using a paperclip to upload a file into my Rails 4 apps.

It needs to be uploaded so that I can access it and then process it to get some data from it and save it into the same model.

First, I though of using `after_save`, but it seems like a waste of resources to save the record into MySQL and updating it right afterward when it finishes processing the file and saving the rest of the data.

Then I thought of using `before_save` to process the file and save the relevant data to the model, this way I would be able to perform just one MySQL save.

The problem arises if paperclip completes the upload after the record has been saved because I need the file in the first place to get the rest of the data.

Does paperclip perform the upload once the record has been saved or is it uploaded at the time the new object is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General rule in Web development is first make it work and then refactor to make it better when you have proper benchmarks/measurements. Don't worry by one extra call to database. If it was like 20 calls to database that I would worry about.

I'm recommending benchmarking applications like https://newrelic.com or if you want something in native Ruby http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how paperclip works internally ( maybe I should look into it ) . But you can access the the temporary file Paperclip created in a before_save method.
I'm using such a 'solution' to extract image dimensions in my app.

```
class Artwork < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :extract_dimensions

  has_attached_file :artwork,
    styles: {
      lg: '500x700>',
      md: '200x300>',
      sm: '200x200>'
    }

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :artwork
  process_in_background :artwork

  validates_uniqueness_of :artwork_file_name, scope: :game_id

private

  def extract_dimensions
    tempfile = artwork.queued_for_write[:original]

    unless tempfile.nil?
      geometry = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(tempfile)
      self.dimensions = [geometry.width.to_i, geometry.height.to_i].join('x')
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not entirely sure whether this performs 1 or 2 queries. In all fairness, because it's done in the background, I don't really care if it does one extra query. Hope it helps you.